# Studio is not working in Sugar 7.0

Tags: php

I am newbie to Sugar 7.0. I am trying to open Studio but studio is not working, it only display the nothing.
I have searched alot, but not found any solution.
Can any body tell me that whats the problem with Sugar7's Studio ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check the Sugar CRM list for bugs if you are sure you have it properly installed. You can do that here: [Sugar 7.0 known issues/bugs](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/04_Sugar_Professional/Sugar_Professional_7.0/Sugar_Professional_7.0.0_Release_Notes). You can also shoot them a report/request here: [Sugar requests/bugs report](http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html)